# c++ get console output without showing console

Tags: c++, console

There are some similar topics on SO, but I haven't found all I need. 
I have the following C++ Code:

```
    string getConsoleOutput(string command)
    {
        string data;
        File *fp;
        char var[512];

        fp = _popen(command.c_str(), "r");
        while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL)
        {
            data += var;
        }
       _pclose(fp);

       return data;
    }
```

The problem is that every time I send a console command to this function, the command  line pops up.

I want to send a command to the Console and get the output without seeing a Console Window.

EDIT:
I tried out libexec, but it is too complex for my needs
I also read about WinExec and CreateProcess, but I haven't found a way to get the output

Comment: Hiding a console window depends on the system. Windows or Unix-land?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention it: Windows

Comment: I think this is O.S. dependant. I don't really know about MS Windows but could you run the process in a thread or something?

Comment: I just found [libexecstream](http://libexecstream.sourceforge.net/) which sounds pretty elegant.. it works on linux and windows

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay with a little flash on the screen, then just include a command to hide the window. Since AFAIK Windows doesn't itself offer such a command (although it may be lurking in the deeps of Powershell), you will have to create it. But that's trivial:

```
#define UNICODE
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );
}
```

I've tested that the `_popen` functionality works OK with hidden window.

And contrary to the documentation, it apparently also works OK for a GUI subsystem application, although I didn't test more than a `dir` command.

---

If the flash is unacceptable, then you can use `CreateProcess` to fire up a hidden command intepreter window, and low level Windows pipes to catch the output.

Sorry, I first wrote a suggestion here about `COMSPEC` and a GUI subsystem *faux* command interpreter, which works as far as I tested it, but it would just involve the above again for catching the command interpreter output. I.e. using `_popen` in the main program would then just be added complication and inefficiency. Better to do it directly at the API level.

---

An example.

*Disclaimer: I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here, because when the command process terminates the pipe should generate EOF, no bytes read. Instead the `ReadFile` call would then just hang, so I had to add a very ugly wait-for-data-or-process-termination loop before calling `ReadFile`. On the other hand, I remember that Windows had some bugs related to pipes and EOF. So pretty sure is not 100% sure, but I haven't had time to check out MS example.*

```
#define NOMINMAX
#define STRICT
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto hopefully( const bool condition ) -> bool { return condition; }
auto fail( const string& message ) -> bool { throw runtime_error( message ); }

struct Non_copyable
{
    Non_copyable& operator=( const Non_copyable& ) = delete;
    Non_copyable( const Non_copyable& ) = delete;
    Non_copyable() {}
    Non_copyable( Non_copyable&& ) {}
};

struct Process
    : Non_copyable
{
    HANDLE handle;

    ~Process() { CloseHandle( handle ); }

    Process( const HANDLE h = 0 ): handle( h ) {}
    Process( Process&& other ): handle( other.handle ) { other.handle = 0; }
};

auto environment_var( const wstring& name )
    -> wstring
{
    const DWORD buffer_size = GetEnvironmentVariable( name.c_str(), nullptr, 0 );
    hopefully( buffer_size > 0 )
        || fail( "environment_var: GetEnvironmentVariable failed 1st call." );
    wstring result( buffer_size + 1, L'#' );
    const DWORD n_characters = GetEnvironmentVariable(
        name.c_str(), &result[0], result.size()
        );
    hopefully( n_characters > 0 )
        || fail( "environment_var: GetEnvironmentVariable failed 2nd call." );
    result.resize( n_characters );      // Just for good measure.
    return result;
}

auto exit_code_of( const HANDLE process )
    -> int
{
    DWORD code = E_FAIL;
    GetExitCodeProcess( process, &code );
    return code;
}

auto has_terminated( const HANDLE process )
    -> bool
{ return exit_code_of( process ) != STILL_ACTIVE; }

auto start_command( const wstring& command, const HANDLE output_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    -> Process
{
    const wstring com_spec = environment_var( L"COMSPEC" );
    wstring command_line = com_spec + L" /c " + command;    // Can not be `const`.

    STARTUPINFO params = { sizeof( STARTUPINFO ) };
    if( output_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        const HANDLE nul = CreateFile( L"nul", GENERIC_ALL, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0 );
        params.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        params.hStdInput = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
        params.hStdOutput = output_handle;
        params.hStdError = GetStdHandle( STD_ERROR_HANDLE );
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION info = {};

    bool const process_was_created = !!CreateProcess(
        nullptr,                // LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
        &command_line[0],       // LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
        nullptr,                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        nullptr,                // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        true,                   // BOOL bInheritHandles,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,       // DWORD dwCreationFlags,
        nullptr,                // LPVOID lpEnvironment,
        nullptr,                // LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
        &params,                // LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        &info                   // LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
        );
    if( not process_was_created ) { return 0; }
    CloseHandle( info.hThread );
    return info.hProcess;
}

auto command_result( const wstring& command )
    -> string
{
    struct Pipe
    {
        HANDLE read_handle  = 0;
        HANDLE write_handle = 0;
        ~Pipe() { CloseHandle( read_handle ); CloseHandle( write_handle ); }
    };

    Pipe pipe;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES params = { sizeof( SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ) };
    params.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    CreatePipe( &pipe.read_handle, &pipe.write_handle, &params, 0 )
        || fail( "command_result: CreatePipe failed" );
    SetHandleInformation( pipe.read_handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0 );   // Inheritance ungood.
    const Process process = { start_command( command, pipe.write_handle ) };
    if( process.handle == 0 ) { return ""; }
    string result;
    for( ;; )
    {
        // Wait for data to become available or process terminated, to avoid hanging.
        for( ;; )
        {
            DWORD n_bytes_available = 0;
            const bool ok = !!PeekNamedPipe(
                pipe.read_handle, nullptr, 0, nullptr, &n_bytes_available, nullptr
                );
            if( ok && n_bytes_available > 0 ) { break; }
            if( has_terminated( process.handle ) ) { return result; }
            Sleep( 125 );
        }
        char buffer[4096];
        DWORD n_bytes_read = 0;
        SetLastError( 0 );
        ReadFile( pipe.read_handle, buffer, sizeof( buffer ), &n_bytes_read, nullptr )
            || fail( "command_result: ReadFile failed" );
        const auto last_read_error = GetLastError();
        if( last_read_error != 0 ) { break; }
        if( n_bytes_read == 0 ) { break; }
        result.append( buffer, n_bytes_read );
    }
    return result;    
}

auto main() -> int
{
    try
    {
        const string result = command_result( L"dir *" );
        const wstring text( result.begin(), result.end() );
        MessageBox( 0, text.c_str(), L"Result:", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
        return 0;
    }
    catch( const exception& x )
    {
        MessageBoxA( 0, x.what(), "Oops, an exception", MB_ICONERROR | MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    }
    return E_FAIL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I experimented with such properties and it works quite well, but the most beautiful solution would be without the flash. Additionally, if you type e. g. `ping localhost` , the console window doesn't just flash, but stays open for some time

Comment: @user3932876: okay, I updated the answer with an additional suggestion. :)